# NTP Server without using System time

Tags: java, time, ntp

I have a desktop PC with no internet connection or GPS receiver. I need to build an NTP server application, preferably in JAVA, without using system time.

I have used the following method.

```
public void run() 
    {
        Date oDate = new Date();
        time = oDate.getTime();

        System.out.println("Syst Time--->"+oDateFormat.format(time));
        while(true)
        {
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                time = time+100;
                oDate = new Date();
                if(time % 11443 == 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("Time--->"+oDateFormat.format(time)+" Syst Time--->"+oDateFormat.format(oDate));
                    oDate = null;
                }
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException ex) 
            {
                Logger.getLogger(NTPServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

What I am doing is there is a thread which sleeps for 100 milliseconds and after that I add 100 to the **time** variable which keeps my time. 
But it creates a 2-3 second difference with the system time every time its printed. Basically its not accurate.

Is there any other way?

Comment: Just relying on sleep() will never be exact enough. Can't you use system time as a base, store the difference between system time and GPS time as offset, and calculate the real time from that when you need it? When you update that offset every few seconds or minutes you should be OK even with a badly drifting system time.

Comment: Actually `new Date()` is already using system time.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker  
Yes, I am assuming System time is correct the first time and then it drifts. So I take the correct time from the system first and then trying to keep it from drifting.

Comment: @ThomasStets But that offset is static right? The drift is a second per hour which is pretty large. So say I get the offset of 1 sec initially, I cant reduce the offset much at the end of the day.

Comment: @Tattu sorry, it seems I didn't read you question careful enough. I read that you *had* GPS data, when you actually said you hadn't. Is the drift of your system time constant, i.e. always one second per hour? Then you can compensate for that if you know how long ago you read the first time. If the drift itself fluctuates you are out of luck. Even if you manage to get some meaning ful information from sleep(), this method itself relies on the system clock. Mayby this can help you tune your clock (if you run Linux): https://www.linux.com/learn/docs/ldp/469-Clock

Comment: The drift fluctuates. Thanks for the link. I will surely go through it. @SpaceTrucker below mentioned System.nanotime() which I am currently trying out.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Thread.sleep(100);` will not ensure that your loop is executed precisely every 100ms. There are at least two things to consider:

- The code itself that you execute between the calls to `Thread.sleep(100)` takes time to execute.
- `Thread.sleep(100)` does not sleep *exactly* 100ms, but it sleeps *at least* 100ms. When your program really continues after `Thread.sleep()` is undefined and depends on implementation-defined aspects like the VM scheduler and the OS scheduler.

Time cannot be measured by software in environments with non-deterministic timing behavior. Non-deterministic timing behavior is caused by schedulers, caches, multitasking, multi-threading, hard disks etc..

You'll have to rely on system time, using `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `System.nanoTime()`.

Comment: Yeah, I knew about sleep(int), but I was just trying to asses how the drift goes. It wont work. Thats the reason why I posted seeking help :)

Comment: And my objective is to minimize the time drift to say 1 second for a week or something around that. But I feel you are right, it seems to be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) as per documentation:

> This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not
>   related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time.

So you won't violate youre requirement in using system time. Then you basically need to do the following:

```
long before = System.nanoTime();
Thread.sleep(100);
long after = System.nanoTime();
time = time+((after-before)/1000000L);
```

You production code should be aware of overflows that might happen to nanoTime during sleep.